# Change detection in Observable inside service not working

Tags: angular

There is a input form control to which I'm subscribing for value changes in service and based on the input value I'm enabling or disabling buttons which are part of the component.

Service

```
nameFormControl: FormControl = new FormControl('', Validators.required);
buttons: string[];
pageInfo;

ngOnInit() {
this.pageInfo = {
    buttons: [{
        name: 'cancel',
        disabled: false,
    },
        name: 'save',
        disabled: true,
    ]
}
    this.nameFormControl.valueChanges.subscribe(() => {
        this.pageInfo.buttons[1].disabled = !this.popupFormControl.valid;
    });
}
```

Button component

```
import {ChangeDetectionStrategy, Component, Input, OnInit} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'button-group',
  templateUrl: `<button *ngFor="button of buttons" type="button" class="button"
            (click)="clicked()"
            [disabled]="button.disabled">{{button.text}}</button>`,
  styles: [],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
})

export class SdxButtonGroupComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() buttons;

  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Here I have set the change detection strategy to onPush, looping through the buttons and rendering them in the UI. When users types something in the input then the 'save' button gets enabled.

Here are the options I have tried:

I have tried to change the reference of the object so that it's immutable

```
const newStateButtons = [...this.pageInfo.buttons];
newStateButtons[1].disabled = !this.nameFormControl.valid;
const newStatePageInfo = Object.assign({}, this.popupInformation);
newStatePageInfo.buttons = newStateButtons;
this.pageInfo = newStatePageInfo;
```

Tried to run the detectchanges() function inside the observable like

```
this.cdr.detectChanges();
```

Tried to run the tick

```
this.cdr.tick();
```

None of them seems to be working. Only when I remove the onPush strategy in the buttons component, it works.

Could someone please let me know why the change detection not working in this case?

Comment: show your button component code

Comment: Why we need service? we can handle everything in component right?

Comment: @Artyom I have added the code for button component

Comment: @SureshKumarAriya Because I am using it across different components and don't want to repeat the same stuff in components.

Comment: did you tried to inject service in your component? how service is related to your button component?

Comment: You should have created shared component and use it everywhere

Comment: @SureshKumarAriya It's designed like that. Can't we trigger change detection from service?

Comment: Inside ButtonComponent, use SetTimeout(()=> {this.cdr.markForCheck();}, 0);

Comment: @SureshKumarAriya No it does not work.

Comment: can you create a stackblitz?

Comment: In Service, you can pass Data using BehaviorSubject.next. In Component you can access using subscribe. This will work

Comment: @SureshKumarAriya I have moved the logic from service to component and now its working fine. Thanks!